# How to make a c# desktop application run on any screen resolution?

Tags: c#

I want to run my desktop program on different screen resolutions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stock {
  public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      this.AutoSize = true;
      this.WindowState = WindowState.maximized;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show what you've tried and isn't working? this isn't a code-writing service. https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20application%20run%20on%20screen%20resolution has some good suggestions

Comment: i tried it on google and found the solution as" make the property of the form as Dock = Fill, and AutoScroll = true then  your form will got same size in different screens" this statement dosenot worked for me then i tried to make windowsState maximized so the form will occupy full screen and it works but the controls like "button,panel,textboxes and etc" was remain at their size while the form is opening on full screen What can i do

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stock
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.AutoSize = true;
  this.WindowState = WindowState.maximized;
            
        }
    }
}

Comment: edit that into your question - don't leave it in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with Winform and WPF, to make things scalable to *most* screen resolutions, you should use some sort of grid or "flow" layout.

In Winforms, this is best accomplished by using a `TableLayoutPanel` control. The layout panels allow you to distribute spacing by percentage and absolute values (much like a table or div in a webpage).

MSDN provides a good walkthrough for this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4yc3e8c(v=vs.90).aspx

Another option is a flow layout.  This is similar to how responsive designed websites "stack" elements in a vertical display that would typically stay side-by-side on a wider display.  Winforms has a control for that layout as well:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.90).aspx

Basically how it works is, you put the layout control on the form. Configure the layout the way you want it to scale, and instead of putting your other controls (buttons, textboxes, etc) directly on the form, you put them in the "cells" of the layout control.

When you apply the `Dock = fill` to the layout control, it will take up the whole area it's assigned to (typically the form itself).  The control placement will then scale with the size of the form based on how you set up the layout control.

Comment: Thanks MutantNinjaCodeMonkey for helping me it worked for me :)